# Не могу добавить клавиатуру в vk api. Помогите пожалуйста

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, клавиатура

Уже на протяжении нескольких месяцев я пытаюсь добавить клавиатуру после нажатия другой кнопки. Например пользователь нажал на клавиатуре "Привет", и по идеи должна появиться клавиатура с кнопкой "Пока". Я еще новичок, помогите пожалуйста
Напишите код в котором есть это всё т.к. ничего не получается

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример кода, если правильно понял вопрос автора:

```
import vk_api
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
from vk_api.keyboard import VkKeyboard, VkKeyboardColor
 
session = vk_api.VkApi(token="TOKEN")
 
 
def send_message(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
    post = {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "message": message,
        "random_id": 0
    }
 
    if keyboard != None:
        post["keyboard"] = keyboard.get_keyboard()
 
    session.method("messages.send", post)
 
 
for event in VkLongPoll(session).listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        text = event.text.lower()
        user_id = event.user_id
 
        if text == "start":
            keyboard = VkKeyboard()
            keyboard.add_location_button()
            keyboard.add_line()

            buttons = ["Привет", "Пока"]
            button_colors = [VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY, VkKeyboardColor.PRIMARY]
 
            for btn, btn_color in zip(buttons, button_colors):
                keyboard.add_button(btn, btn_color)
 
            send_message(user_id, "The first button!", keyboard)
 
        elif text == "Привет":
            send_message(user_id, "Вы нажали на кнопку 'Привет'")
        elif text == "Пока":
            send_message(user_id, "Вы нажали на кнопку 'Пока'")
```

Comment: Нет, не особо правильно поняли. Нужно что бы выдавали еще одну клавиатуру после нажатия любой кнопки (клавиатура с разными текстами нужна)

Comment: @Anonim Anonimous А зачем вам две клавиатуры? Разве не лучше, когда у пользователя одна клавиатура с кнопками.

Comment: нужно что бы менялись именно